# On pbs how to move a running job to another node to continue?

Tags: pbs

I first `qsub` many tasks on node05. Then I find the node06 is free and I want to move a task on node05 to node06 to continue.

I find some commands like `qhold`, `qrls`, `qmove` and `qalter` that look like the appropriate methods. But there is no any example just simple description.

So can anyone help, teach or take some examples about moving a task from a node to another one to continue please?